# Open different web pages using different buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, web

I have many buttons in an Activity and clicking them I need to open different web pages whose URLs are stocked in an ArrayList collection. I want to use a loop but I get a "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method".

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  public List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
  public static final int NRBUTTONS = 7;
  ..........................        
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..........
    ..........  
    int id = R.id.button1 - 1;
    for (int index=0; index<NRBUTTONS; index++) {

   Button b = (Button) findViewById(++id);
   String text = titles.get(index);
   b.setText(text);

   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW,   
                    Uri.parse(links.get(index)));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
     }
  });
   }
   ...........
}
```

Also, if you could help me please with the

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
```

How could I write this in a loop?

Comment: There's quite a bit wrong with your code. First off, you can NOT assume that ids are sequential and contiguous. Using `findViewById(++id)` will almost certainly break with ClassCastException. Secondly, rather than creating four OnClickListeners, just create one and attach it to all your buttons. Then in the listener, use a `switch(arg0.getId())` statement to dispatch the proper intent.

Comment: @323go thank you, I know findViewById(++id) is very wrong, how could I make findViewById in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick outline of a pattern I frequently use when I do this sort of thing:

```
private static final int[] buttonIds = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);

    for (int i=0; i<buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button b = (Button) findViewById( buttonIds[i] );
        if( b != null ) {
            // Assign onClickListener, etc.
        } else {
            // Log This; shouldn't happen
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

and an example of a universal `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch( v.getTag() ) {
        case R.id.Button1:
            /// Do something for Button1
            break;
        case R.id.Button2:
            /// Do something for Button2
            break;
        case R.id.Button3:
            /// Do something for Button3
            break;
        case R.id.Button4:
            /// Do something for Button4
            break;
        default:
            /// Log this; shouldn't happen
    }
}
```

Also a quick tip to save you a few headaches: If you declare your `Activity` class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

then your `onClick()` callback can simply be a method of the Activity class. This then simplifies your assignments to:

```
b.setOnClickListener( this );
```

I personally prefer this over creating separate callbacks for the various buttons, as it keeps everything nicely organized. Other programmers have different preferences, and they are no better or worse, IMO.

Comment: Thank you again. I have used public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { } and it

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your app1

Comment: Thank you, you have helped me a lot. Gook luck you too with your site.